# Insight on the polar decomposition of a shear?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, transformation

I recently learned it, and really love the polar decomposition of a matrix, because it was the first time I actually could picture what it meant to "apply a transformation to space" *(a phrase I kept on seeing being thrown about in forums and videos).*

We can picture any linear transformation as scaling along orthogonal directions *(along the eigenvectors of $S$ in the decomposition)*, and then rotating. $$A=QS$$

Decompositions have helped me understand lots of properties about linear transformations. What I'm wondering right now is if there's any special or enlightening characteristics about the polar decomposition of a **shear.**

I'm not sure if "shear" is the correct term, but I mean a transformation like this one:

\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

This transformation doesn't rotate space, and it only has one eigenvector. I tried using a polar decomposition calculator online, but it kept on failing me...

Any help? Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: The polar decomposition of this matrix is quite ugly, but any calculator worth its salt should be able to produce it. Try computing the SVD and forming the polar decomposition from that instead.

Comment: I’d be interested to see what insights you can from the polar decomposition of a shear. For me, it makes more sense to look at it as a variable-distance translation parallel to the eigenvectors.

Comment: @amd yea, I calculated the decomposition like a minute after I posted the question, but when I saw how ugly it was, I decided perhaps it was best not to post it, to not discourage people with ugly numbers from trying to find some insights before they even tried! There's gotta be some insight though! Maybe if we somehow found a prettier symmetric matrix....Anyways, I would love it if you could elaborate on what you mean by a "variable-distance translation parallel to the eigenvectors!!!" It definitely sounds insightful!

Comment: @amd What is 'quite ugly' for you in the polar context? Triggered by this word I began to calculate & posted subsequently.

Comment: @Hanno I was looking at the SVD, which didn’t immediately look like it would simply nicely when constructing the polar decomposition from it, and completely overlooked the fact that this particular matrix generates Fibonacci sequences.

Comment: @amd but wait a sec, I still do want to look at the SVD!!! Not just because it generates Fibonacci sequences! Geometrically, is there anything special about the SVD or polar decomposition of shears simply because they only have a single eigenvector, and a determinant of 1? Even if it didn't generate the Fibonacci sequence...for example, if it was: \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} instead!!! I feel like there would be, just from it being a shear!!!

Comment: @Hanno the above comment goes out to you as well!

Answer (score 2):

This post has been triggered by mentioning 'ugly' in the comments ...

G. H. Hardy once wrote (in "A Mathematician's Apology", 1941)
*Beauty is the first test: There is no permanent place in the world for ugly mathematics.*
See also on Philosophy.SE the post [What did Hardy mean by “ugly mathematics”?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/12749) .

---

***Let software*** work on $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

`python.scipy.linalg.polar(A)` yields the polar decomposition

```
 Q = [[ 0.89442719,  0.4472136 ],
      [-0.4472136 ,  0.89442719]]

 S = [[ 0.89442719,  0.4472136 ],
      [ 0.4472136 ,  1.34164079]]
```

Notice that $\,0.4472136=1\big/{\sqrt 5}\,$.

***Manual handling*** of $A$

We determine $\,S=|A|\,$ first.
$$S^2\,=\,A^*\!A\:=\:\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}
\;\text{ has the eigenvalues }
\left(\frac{\sqrt 5\pm 1}2\right)^2\,,$$
hence it's positive-definite.
$\frac{\sqrt 5+1}2=1.618034$ is the Golden ratio, which in the sequel is denoted by $\phi$. Note that it satisfies

- $\phi^2=\phi +1\iff \phi(\phi -1) =1$
- $\phi +2=\sqrt5\,\phi$

This helps in identifying eigenvectors of $S^2$ as
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \phi\end{pmatrix}
 \:=\: \phi^2\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \phi\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}-\phi\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
 \:=\: (\phi-1)^2\begin{pmatrix}-\phi\\1\end{pmatrix}\,.$$
They are also eigenvectors of $S$ to the eigenvalues $\phi$ and $\phi -1$.
Incorporating normalisation factors one gets
$$\begin{align}
S \:& =\frac1{\sqrt{\phi^2+1}}\begin{pmatrix}1&-\phi\\ \phi&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\phi&0\\0&\phi-1\end{pmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt{\phi^2+1}}\begin{pmatrix}1&\phi\\ -\phi&1\end{pmatrix}
 \:=\: \frac1{\phi+2}\begin{pmatrix}2\phi&\phi\\ \phi&3\phi\end{pmatrix} \\[2ex]
 & =\frac1{\sqrt 5}\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

As $S\,$ is positive-definite, thus invertible, the unitary factor $Q$ in the polar decomposition may be obtained as
$$Q\,=\,AS^{-1}\:=\:\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\,\frac1{\sqrt 5}\begin{pmatrix}3&-1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}\;=\;
\frac1{\sqrt 5}\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}$$
*In summary
$$A\:=\:\frac1{\sqrt 5}\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}\:
\frac1{\sqrt 5}\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}\,,$$
and where's the ugliness?*

Comment: Holy shenanigans Hanno. I'm going to be honest with you, I know nothing about the golden ratio, but I'm going to look more into your answer! I'll get back to you! But, before I do, is there any part I should look out for in the decomposition that's special because this matrix only has one eigenvector (since shears in general only have one eigenvector)?

Comment: So, to the OP’s underlying question, what insights does this decomposition give you into the operation of this shear, and shear transformations in general?